# KafkaListener errorHandler not catching the exception

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I have an error handler of type `KafkaListenerErrorHandler` defined in  `KafkaListener`. After reading record from topic I am saving in MongoDB. In some case I will get `DuplicateKeyException` which is not being caught by my error handler rather catch inside `InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke()`. I want to catch and log the message instead of printing default long stack track. Feels like I am missing a layer of config. Can someone help me out. TIA

KafkaListener

```
@KafkaLister(topics="myTopic" groupId="myGroup" errorHandler="myErrorHandler"
public void consume(ConsumerRecord<String, MyRecord> consumerRecord) {
  myDbService.saveRecord(consumerRecord.value());
}
```

Error Handler

```
public class MyErrorHandler implements ConsumerAwareListenerErrorHandler {
  @Override
  public Object handleError(....) {
    log.error("Error!!!");
  }
}
```

Exception chain

```
MongoWriteException > DuplicateKeyException > ListenerExecutionFailedException > KafkaException
```

Exception Snippet

```
Error handler threw an exception
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Seek to current after exception; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.listenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'public void com.myapp.myconsumer.consume(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord<java.lang.String, com.myapp.domain.MyRecord>)' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: Write operation error on server somehost.com:29000. Write error: WriteError{code=11000, message='.....'', details={}}.; nested exption is com.mongodb.MomgoWriteException: Write operation error on server .....
```

Comment: Show us, please, a stack trace you got in those logs.

Comment: @ArtemBilan - Added stack trace

Comment: `Error handler threw an exception` - looks like your `MyErrorHandler` is not called or it throws an exception back. Care to share a simple project to let us reproduce?

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So76708547Application {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(So76708547Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So76708547Application.class, args);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so76708547", topics = "so76708547", errorHandler = "myErrorHandler")
    void listen(String in) {
        log.info(in);
        throw new RuntimeException("test");
    }

    @Bean
    NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so76708547").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> {
            template.send("so76708547", "foo");
        };
    }

}

@Component
class MyErrorHandler implements ConsumerAwareListenerErrorHandler {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyErrorHandler.class);

    @Override
    public Object handleError(Message<?> message, ListenerExecutionFailedException exception, Consumer<?, ?> consumer) {
        log.error("Error!!!");
        return null;
    }

}
```

```
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
logging.pattern.console= %5p [%t] %m%n
```

```
 INFO [so76708547-0-C-1] so76708547: partitions assigned: [so76708547-0]
 INFO [so76708547-0-C-1] foo
ERROR [so76708547-0-C-1] Error!!!
```

If you can't figure out what's different for you, post an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) someplace.